# Sum values of column by row and get the column that hits x % of total

Tags: python, pandas

Okay, this is a bit difficult to describe. Basically, I have a dataframe like the following, where each column (from 0-90) represent a day, from day-0 to 90 days after day-90, and the numbers on each cell are sums of a certain feature for that ID in that day:

```
        ID      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       A       2   21  0   18  3   0   0   0   2   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    156
1       B       0   20  12  2   0   8   14  23  0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    231
2       C       0   38  19  3   1   3   3   7   1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     78
3       D       3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0      5
```

What I need is the **first one** is a new column that displays the *number of the column at which the sum of previous values hit 90% of the 'total' value*. **Example**: For the first row, I want to know when (which day, somewhere between 0-90) the sum of values for that ID hit 90% of the total, which is 156. I would have a new column that would hold the value for the day that summed up to 90% of the total, something like this:

```
        ID      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ... 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  total  day_90%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       A       2   21  0   18  3   0   0   0   2   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    156   54
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: convert the data to rows using the pandas `melt` function, instead of having them with columns. Then it becomes a simple matter of sorting and using `cumsum` function

Comment: I'm actually quite lost for this one, I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_pct = df.cumsum(axis=1).div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

df['day_90%'] = (df_pct > .9).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Use `idxmax` to return the first time True where cumulative percent is greater than .9.

Comment: I had to add .loc[:, '0':'90'] since I added the total beforehand, but yes it works perfectly. Thanks a million =)

Comment: I added another question for a sort of sequence to this one, as it is another thing that is a bit out of my league. If you could take a look, here is the link for it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581340/length-of-first-sequence-of-zeros-of-given-size-after-certain-column-in-pandas-d